# boost::date_time error while building MongoDB: winapi is not member

Tags: c++, mongodb, boost, boost-date-time

While building MongoDB with SCons and boost, I'm getting errors.  Here's my command line:

> C:\mongo-cxx-driver>Scons --prefix=$HOME/mongo-client-lib --cpppath=C:\boost_1_66_0 --libpath=C:\boost_1_66_0\stage64\lib --dbg=on --64 install

Here are the error messages I'm getting:

```
src\mongo\util\time_support.cpp(904): error C2039: 'winapi': is not a member of 'boost::date_time'
C:\boost_1_66_0\boost/date_time/filetime_functions.hpp(28): note: see declaration of 'boost::date_time'
src\mongo\util\time_support.cpp(904): error C3083: 'winapi': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
src\mongo\util\time_support.cpp(904): error C2039: 'file_time_to_microseconds': is not a member of 'boost::date_time'
C:\boost_1_66_0\boost/date_time/filetime_functions.hpp(28): note: see declaration of 'boost::date_time'
src\mongo\util\time_support.cpp(904): error C3861: 'file_time_to_microseconds': identifier not found
src\mongo\util\time_support.cpp(936): error C2039: 'winapi': is not a member of 'boost::date_time'
C:\boost_1_66_0\boost/date_time/filetime_functions.hpp(28): note: see declaration of 'boost::date_time'
src\mongo\util\time_support.cpp(936): error C3083: 'winapi': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
src\mongo\util\time_support.cpp(936): error C2039: 'file_time_to_microseconds': is not a member of 'boost::date_time'
C:\boost_1_66_0\boost/date_time/filetime_functions.hpp(28): note: see declaration of 'boost::date_time'
src\mongo\util\time_support.cpp(936): error C3861: 'file_time_to_microseconds': identifier not found
scons: *** [build\win32\64\dbg_on\mongo\util\time_support.obj] Error 2
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Comment: The below answer is correct, but the good news is that we are working on fixing it. See my comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL; DR** - You can't expect to pick an arbitrary or current version of a library and build MongoDB with it; they snapshot their dependencies in their repo and there's no promises about building with versions besides those.

---

MongoDB has snapshots of its dependencies in the [src/thirdparty directory](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/master/src/third_party).  The version of boost snapshotted there is 1.60, which was [released in 2015](https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_60_0.html).  You can see that in that version of boost, there is a `winapi` namespace defined in [`boost/date_time/filetime_functions.hpp`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/3b1996c97a6fee6b49baed1f64a00c880f81ae6a/src/third_party/boost-1.60.0/boost/date_time/filetime_functions.hpp#L34).

However, you're trying to build against boost 1.66, which was [released in December 2017](https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_66_0.html).  The release notes mention changes to date_time:

> **DateTime:**
>
> - The library has been converted to use Boost.WinAPI as the abstraction layer for Windows SDK.
> - Fixed an integral overflow that could cause incorrect results when adding or subtracting many years from a date (see here).

That version of filetime_functions does not have this namespace inside of date_time, nor does the [current 1.67 snapshot of filetime_functions.hpp](https://github.com/boostorg/date_time/blob/develop/include/boost/date_time/filetime_functions.hpp).

Looking at the [git blame log for src/mongo/util/time_support.cpp](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blame/3b1996c97a6fee6b49baed1f64a00c880f81ae6a/src/mongo/util/time_support.cpp#L832), it looks like the mongo code in question mentioning `date_time::winapi` was added 3 years ago (before this winapi refactoring) and hasn't changed since.

Comment: We are actually right now in the process of upgrading our vendored boost dependency and encountered this issue. We will be fixing it soon.

Comment: @FlorianWinter - Yes, MongoDB 4.2 has been upgraded to boost 1.70.

Answer (score 0):

If you are desperate, and you are still using the end-of-life legacy MongoDB driver (which you shouldn't!) and cannot update all your code at this time (which you have to, eventually!), and you need a quick patch, then you can insert the following code (taken from [Boost 1.53.0](https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_53_0.html)) into `time_support.cpp`:

```
namespace boost {
  namespace date_time {
    namespace winapi {
    /*!
     * The function converts file_time into number of microseconds elapsed since 1970-Jan-01
     *
     * \note Only dates after 1970-Jan-01 are supported. Dates before will be wrapped.
     *
     * \note The function is templated on the FILETIME type, so that
     *       it can be used with both native FILETIME and the ad-hoc
     *       boost::date_time::winapi::file_time type.
     */
    template< typename FileTimeT >
    inline boost::uint64_t file_time_to_microseconds(FileTimeT const& ft)
    {
        /* shift is difference between 1970-Jan-01 & 1601-Jan-01
        * in 100-nanosecond intervals */
        const uint64_t shift = 116444736000000000ULL; // (27111902 << 32) + 3577643008

        union {
            FileTimeT as_file_time;
            uint64_t as_integer; // 100-nanos since 1601-Jan-01
        } caster;
        caster.as_file_time = ft;

        caster.as_integer -= shift; // filetime is now 100-nanos since 1970-Jan-01
        return (caster.as_integer / 10); // truncate to microseconds
    }
    }
  }
}
```

This will define the missing function.